# Vertical and horizontal centering of the block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to center red block **Horizontally and Vertically** as in the picture below, but unfortunately red block is placed in the wrong place. I use bootstrap 4. Сan anyone say what's wrong??

[image]

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header-layout">
    *Some content*
  </div>

  <div class="row content-layout">
    <div class="col-6 left-side">
      *Some content*
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 right-side">
      <div class="row right-title">
        *Some Text*
      </div>
      <div class="row parent">
        <div class="child">
          *Some content*
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you did nothing wrong ... add   width: 300px; background: red; height:300px; to .parent and you will see that its centered

Comment: Well it works when parent has height, but how to make the height of .parent equal to the remaining space until the end of the height of the content-layout. I am trying give height: 100% but parent element became bigger that content-layout

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for effortless centering of element.

Here's a full guide for [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; }
  
.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just change some bootstrap class and css. hope it help :)

```css
div {
  border: thin solid black;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header-layout">
    *Container content*
  </div>

  <div class="row content-layout">
    <div class="col-6 left-side">
      *left content*
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 right-side">
      <div class="row right-title">
        *Right Text*
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="child">
          *Child content*
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code centering only Horizontally. In my case parent`s hieght is unknown.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek i did not set any height attr for parent div as you can see :-s. its height is base on content's height

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the new **Bootstrap 4 flexbox utilities**..

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row header-layout">
    *Some content*
  </div>

  <div class="row content-layout flex-grow">
    <div class="col-6 left-side d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-grow">
            <div class="col-12 text-center my-auto">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 right-side d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row right-title"> 
        <div class="col-12 text-center">title</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row parent flex-grow">
        <div class="child col-6 mx-auto my-auto">
          <div class="card card-block">child</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6nALguHQyw

Just make sure the body,html are 100% height. Also, I added a `flex-grow` class to make content fill the remaining height. In the future, [this may be added as a util class](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21944) so that you won't need this extra CSS.